# Rename unnamed multiindex columns in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I created this dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("x", "", ""), ("values", "a", "a.b"), ("values", "c", "")])
df0 = pd.DataFrame([(0,10,20),(1,100,200)], columns=columns)
df0
```

[image]

I unload `df0` to excel:

```
df0.to_excel("test.xlsx")
```

and load it again:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", header=[0,1,2])
df1
```

[image]

And I have `Unnamed :...` column names.

To make `df1` look like inital `df0` I run:

```
def rename_unnamed(df, label=""):
    for i, columns in enumerate(df.columns.levels):
        columns = columns.tolist()
        for j, row in enumerate(columns):
            if "Unnamed: " in row:
                columns[j] = ""
        df.columns.set_levels(columns, level=i, inplace=True)
    return df

rename_unnamed(df1)
```

[image]

Well done. But is there any pandas way from box to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with condition by [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
for i, col in enumerate(df1.columns.levels):
    columns = np.where(col.str.contains('Unnamed'), '', col)
    df1.columns.set_levels(columns, level=i, inplace=True)

print (df1)
   x values     
          a    c
        a.b     
0  0     10   20
1  1    100  200
```

Comment: Unfortunately in pandas is no function for this. `str.contains` works only with `Series`, so need `for`.

Comment: As @dinya says this code works for pandas version below 0.21.0. See his/her answer for an update.

Answer (score 6):

Since pandas 0.21.0 the code should be like this

```
def rename_unnamed(df):
    """Rename unamed columns name for Pandas DataFrame

    See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221079/rename-multiindex-columns-in-pandas

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : pd.DataFrame object
        Input dataframe

    Returns
    -------
    pd.DataFrame
        Output dataframe

    """
    for i, columns in enumerate(df.columns.levels):
        columns_new = columns.tolist()
        for j, row in enumerate(columns_new):
            if "Unnamed: " in row:
                columns_new[j] = ""
        if pd.__version__ < "0.21.0":  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/48186976/716469
            df.columns.set_levels(columns_new, level=i, inplace=True)
        else:
            df = df.rename(columns=dict(zip(columns.tolist(), columns_new)),
                           level=i)
    return df
```

Comment: Great solution. I'm trying to do something similar based off your function but can't do it. Would you care to take a look:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61111336/pandas-dataframes-with-multi-level-columnsrename-a-specific-level-of-column-so?

Answer (score 4):

Mixing answers from @jezrael and @dinya, and limited for pandas above 0.21.0 (after 2017) an option to solve this will be:

```
for i, columns_old in enumerate(df.columns.levels):
    columns_new = np.where(columns_old.str.contains('Unnamed'), '-', columns_old)
    df.rename(columns=dict(zip(columns_old, columns_new)), level=i, inplace=True)
```