# Combining MultiIndex columns with similar root names in Pandas/Python

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, multi-index

I have a MultiIndex dataframe with the top level columns named:

> Col1_1 | Col1_2 | Col 2_1 | Col 2_2 | ... |

I'm looking to combine Col1_1 with Col1_2 as Col1. I could also do this before creating the MultiIndex, but the original data is more drawn out as:

> Col1_1.aspect1 | Col1_1.aspect 2 | Col1_2.aspect1 | Col1_2.aspect2 | ... |

where 'aspect1' and 'aspect2' become subcolumns in the MultiIndex.

Please let me know if I can clarify anything, and many thanks in advance.

[image: Current df]

The expected result combines the two as just Sample1; any number of ways is fine, including stacking/concatenating the data, outputting a summary stat e.g. mean(), etc.

Comment: share df.head()

Comment: I've previously found similar questions, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221079/rename-multiindex-columns-in-pandas , but I don't believe this is quite right for this problem.

Comment: again, share a sample and share an example of your expected result

Comment: :) we commented ~simultaneously as you can see by the time stamps, I didn't ignore your share request. I've uploaded a snip of the df (it contains hundreds of cols, thousands of rows). Many outputs would work here, as noted above. Thanks.

Comment: thanks, so basically what does it mean with your actual columns? Are you trying to like merge gtype, score etc. columns from sample11 and sample12 in one unique column? or something else

Comment: I'm trying to merge Gtype from Sample1_1 and Sample1_2 into a single sub-column, Gtype under Sample1. Ditto for the other second level columns, Score, Theta, etc. It would also work fine to just output the mean of all values in a new table (GType doesn't matter to me in this case so nan is fine, but the column with numbers do). Thanks for the assist; I hope I'm not overly complicating this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby` and apply an aggregation function against it like `mean`.
You must group against axis 1 (columns) and with level 1 (lower multiindex columns). It will apply the grouping across all samples. Then simply do a mean if it's what you want to achieve:

```
df.groupby(level=1, axis=1).mean()
```

Comment: Thanks! Knowing 'levels' is really helpful for a Python newbie like myself. This is a great start, though I receive: 'DataError: No numeric types to aggregate'. I'll see if I can find the issue then add it here and mark accepted to close it out.

Comment: That s likely because of your text columns: filter them out from the dataframe before grouping