# Renaming multiindex columns with arbitrary order and duplicate column names

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a `DataFrame` `overview` (shortened for this question).

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> index = pd.Index(['Abbott PLC', 'Abbott, Rogahn and Bednar'], dtype='object', name='Account Name')
>>> columns = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['total', 'quantity'], ['count', 'sum']], labels=[[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]])
>>> values = np.array([[755.44,   1.  ,  19.  ], [615.6 ,   1.  ,  18.  ]])
>>> 
>>> overview = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=columns, index=index)
>>> overview
                            total       quantity
                              sum count      sum
Account Name                                    
Abbott PLC                 755.44   1.0     19.0
Abbott, Rogahn and Bednar  615.60   1.0     18.0
```

The column names are weird because in my actual code, this result is derived from a `DataFrame` `df` with the following grouping operation.

```
aggregators = {'total': ['sum', 'count'], 'quantity': 'sum'}
overview = df.groupby('Account Name')['total', 'quantity'].agg(aggregators)
```

I want to rename the columns of `overview`, the desired result looks like this:

```
                            gross  checkouts  items
Account Name                                       
Abbott PLC                 755.44        1.0   19.0
Abbott, Rogahn and Bednar  615.60        1.0   18.0
```

I cannot simply use `overview.columns = ['gross', 'checkouts', 'items']` or the answers from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221079/rename-multiindex-columns-in-pandas) because after using `agg` the columns are in arbitrary order. (Applying `rename` also seems tricky because of the duplicate name `'sum'`.)

Currently, I am working around the problem by using an `OrderedDict` for `aggregators`, thus `overview` having a deterministic column oder. But assuming the creation of `overview` cannot be fixed upstream, how would I arrive at my desired result elegantly?

Comment: If you flatten and join your columns , you'll be left with something like `Index(['total_sum', 'total_count', 'quantity_sum'], dtype='object')`, which will be unique, then you can rename off of that if I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: @user3483203 that sounds promising, feel free to write an answer teaching me the flatten and join process.

Comment: Try using `overview.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() for col in overview.columns.values]` and see if that's the route you want to take, if it is, I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: @user3483203 that seems to work fine. I'm wondering if there's a more "pandas native" solution but for now it does the trick!

Comment: I don't know of a better way builtin to pandas, but glad I could help!

Comment: how about  `overview.set_axis(1,overview.columns.ravel()).rename(columns={('total','sum'):'gross',('total','count'):'checkouts'})`

Comment: @Ian why not post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dataframe has a `MultiIndex` as columns. There are few ways you can flatten into a regular index:

#### pd.Index.map

```
overview.columns = overview.columns.map('_'.join)
```

#### list comprehension + f-strings

With Python 3.6+ you can use formatted string literals ([PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)):

```
overview.columns = [f'{i}_{j}' for i, j in overview.columns]
```

#### list comprehension + str.format / str.join

For versions <3.6, you can use `str.format` or `str.join`:

```
overview.columns = ['{i}_{j}'.format(i, j) for i, j in overview.columns]

overview.columns = list(map('_'.join, overview.columns))
```

---

To only rename, you can use a dictionary mapping directly:

```
d = {('total', 'sum'): 'gross', ('total', 'count'): 'checkouts',
     ('quantity', 'sum'): 'items'}

overview.columns = np.vectorize(d.get)(overview.columns)
```

Comment: Thanks. I know how to proceed from the temporary column names. For completeness you might consider including the final renaming in the answer.

Comment: @timgeb, Sure, I've also added a more direct method, which doesn't require an intermediary renaming.

Comment: Now I understand. The container `overview.columns` works very differently than what its printout would suggest. In fact,  I can treat it just like a list of tuples `[('total', 'sum'), ('total', 'count'), ('quantity', 'sum')]` in this context.

Comment: @timgeb, Exactly so. There's even a method to construct an `Index` from a list of tuples: [`pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html).