# How to fix reading a CSV where column MultiIndex header row(s) have missing values?

Tags: python, pandas

I try to read in several csv files with a unfortunate structure, here's a simplified example:

```
[empty], A, A, B, B
time   , X, Y, X, Y
0.0    , 0, 0, 0, 0
1.0    , 2, 5, 7, 0
...    , ., ., ., .
```

...using `pandas.read_csv` with the `header=[0,1]` argument I can access the values fine:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=[0,1]'
>>> df.A.X
0 0
1 2
...
```

But the empty field above the time header results in an ugly `Unnamed: 0_level_0` level:

```
>>> df.columns
MultiIndex(levels=[['Unnamed: 0_level_0', 'A', 'B'], ...
```

Is there any way to fix this, so I can access the time data with `df.Time` again?

**EDIT:**

This is a snippet of the actual data set:

```
,,Bone,Bone,Bone
,,Skeleton1_Hip,Skeleton1_Hip,Skeleton1_Hip
,,"1","1","1"
,,Rotation,Rotation,Rotation
Frame,Time,X,Y,Z
0,0.000000,0.009332,0.999247,0.021044
1,0.008333,0.009572,0.999217,0.020468
3,0.016667,0.009871,0.999183,0.019797
```

(see also: https://gist.github.com/fhaust/25ba612f99420d366f0597b15dbf43e7 for a more complete example)

read via:

```
pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=2, header=[0,1,3,4], index_col=[1])
```

I don't really care about the `Frame` column, as it's given implicitly with the row index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename MultiIndex columns in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221079/rename-multiindex-columns-in-pandas)

Comment: Not really a duplicate IMHO, their question is more about renaming the columns, mine is more about how to correctly read in the data while preserving the layout of the data.

Comment: The title is overly general; strictly this **isn't** an "unbalanced column MultiIndex", **it's only a CSV file where the first 1/2 columns of the two header rows are missing**. Those can easily be fixed or kludged. The general case (which this isn't) is infinitely harder. Fixed the title.

Answer (score 1):

Add parameter `index_col` for convert first column to `index`:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u""",A,A,B,B
time,X,Y,X,Y
0.0,0,0,0,0
1.0,2,5,7,0"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), header=[0,1], index_col=[0])

print (df)
      A     B   
time  X  Y  X  Y
0.0   0  0  0  0
1.0   2  5  7  0
```

Or rename column:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0_level_0':'val'})
print (df)
   val  A     B   
  time  X  Y  X  Y
0  0.0  0  0  0  0
1  1.0  2  5  7  0
```

Comment: But this removes the hierarchical part of the index: `df.columns -> Index([('A','X'), ('A','Y'), ('B','X'), ('B','Y')])`

Comment: @fho - so data are fifferent like in my answer? I get `print (df.index)
Float64Index([0.0, 1.0], dtype='float64')`

Comment: apparently, I've added a snippet of my file to the question

Comment: @fho - hmmm, is possible upload file (gdocs, dropbox, ...)? Because copy from text should changed data and hard to get same output.