# How to use "Named aggregation"

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I want to apply two different aggregates on the same column in a pandas DataFrameGroupBy and have the new columns be named.

I've tried using what is shown here in the documentation.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation

> ```
> In [82]: animals.groupby("kind").agg(
>    ....:     min_height=('height', 'min'),
>    ....:     max_height=('height', 'max'),
>    ....:     average_weight=('weight', np.mean),
>    ....: )
>    ....: 
> Out[82]: 
>       min_height  max_height  average_weight
> kind                                        
> cat          9.1         9.5            8.90
> dog          6.0        34.0          102.75
> ```

Something like what I'm trying to do is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"year": [2001, 2001, 2001, 2005, 2005],
                   "value": [1, 2, 5, 3, 1]})

df = df.groupby("year").agg(sum=('value', 'sum'),
                            count=('value', 'size'))
```

However, this gives the following:

```
TypeError: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'
```

Comment: I wrote a _very_ detailed answer on named aggregation [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54300159/4909087) You're essentially asking how to aggregate with multiple functions on the same column.

Comment: Yeah, I read your post before I posted this question and I just recently installed pandas so I thought I had the most updated version. I reinstalled to 0.25.0 and of course, it works now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you need two aggfunction for one columns , you may need to pass to list like when you are not update your `pandas` to 0.25.0

```
df = df.groupby("year").value.agg(['sum','count'])
df
      sum  count
year            
2001    8      3
2005    4      2
```

In `pandas` 0.25.0

```
pd.__version__
'0.25.0'
df = df.groupby("year").agg(sum=('value', 'sum'),
                            count=('value', 'count'))
df
      sum  count
year            
2001    8      3
2005    4      2
```

Comment: I just recently installed pandas so I thought I had the most updated version. I reinstalled to 0.25.0 and of course, it works now.