# Get the index corresponding to True boolen values only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After doing some operations, I am getting a dataframe with an index and a column with boolean values. I just need to get those indexes having boolean value to be True. How can I get that?
My output is like this: Here, "AC name" is the index as per the output dataframe.

```
 AC name
Agiaon            False
Alamnagar         False
Alauli            True
Alinagar          False
Ziradei           True
Name: Vote percentage, Length: 253, dtype: bool
```

Comment: What's the name of the column with the boolean values?

Comment: @Barmar, Vote percentage.

Comment: Store this series in a variable say `var` and then `var=var[var].index`

Comment: ```df[df['Vote percentage']]```, you can add ```.index``` at the end to only get an array of indexes

Comment: @AnuragDabas, Could you please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67937940/getting-rows-for-increasing-values-of-a-column-in-each-group-in-grouped-datafram? Just one last request. Unable to get this. Please!!

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the dataframe is `df`, it would be:

```py
res = df[df['Vote percentage']].index
```