# Python Pandas can do these tasks?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series data frame for eight Years (2013-2020) has Hourly data, each Year has Nine zones, under each zone two columns("Gen", "Load") as follows:

```
                            A ZONE         B ZONE               ...   G ZONE       H ZONE           I ZONE         
        date_time           GEN    LOAD    GEN    LOAD          ...    LOAD      GEN    LOAD         GEN    LOAD
    2013-01-01 00:00:00    725.7 5,859.5  312.2 3,194.7        ...    77.1      706.0 227.1        495.0   861.9
    2013-01-01 01:00:00    436.2 450.5    248.0 198.0          ...    865.5     240.7 107.9        640.5 767.3
    2013-01-01 02:00:00    464.5 160.2    144.2 068.3          ...    738.7     044.7 32.7         509.3 700.4
    2013-01-01 03:00:00    169.9 733.8    268.1 869.5          ...    671.7     649.4 951.3        626.8 652.1
    2013-01-01 04:00:00    145.4 553.4    280.2 872.8          ...    761.5     561.0 912.9        552.1 637.3
...                  ...        ...     ...        ...          ...  ...        ...         ...     ...         ...     ...
    2020-12-31 19:00:00    450.9 951.7    371.4 516.3          ...    461.7     808.9 471.4        983.7 447.8
    2020-12-31 20:00:00    553.0 936.5    848.7 233.9          ...    397.3     978.3 404.3        490.9 233.0
    2020-12-31 21:00:00    458.6 735.6    716.8 121.7          ...    385.1     808.0 192.0        131.5 70.1
    2020-12-31 22:00:00    515.8 651.6    693.5 142.4          ...    291.4     826.1 16.8         591.9 863.2
    2020-12-31 23:00:00    218.6 293.4    448.2 14.2           ...    340.6     435.0 897.4        622.5 768.3
```

What I want is the following:

1- Detect outliers in each column which is more or less three time Standard Deviation
of that column and put it in a new column its name "A_gen_outliers" if the there is
outliers in "GEN"column under "A Zone" as well as "A_load_outliers" if the there is
outliers in "LOAD"column under "A Zone". Number of new columns are 18 columns.

2- A new column represents sum of "Gen" columns

3- A new column represents sum of "Load" columns

4- A new column represents "GEN" column calculate A_GEN_div = cell value/maximum value of "GEN column under A Zone for each year  for example 725.7/725.7=1 for the first cell and 436.2/725.1 for second cell and for last cell 218.6/553. etc. and the same for all "GEN" columns and also for "LOAD" columns- proposed names  "A_Load_div".

Number of new columns are 18 columns.

Number of total new columns are "18 *2 + 2" columns

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @gofvonx The first level of the columns is the X Zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help. Note that this will keep the columns `MultiIndex`. Your points above seem to imply that you want to flatten your `MultIndex`. If this is the case, you might want to look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507794/pandas-how-to-flatten-a-hierarchical-index-in-columns/55757002#55757002).

1:

```
df.join(df>(3*df.std()), rsuffix='_outlier')
```

2 and 3:

```
df.groupby(level=-1, axis=1).sum()
```

Note that it is not clear from what the first level of the columns `MultIndex` should be for this.

4:

```
maxima = df.resample('1Y').max()
maxima.index = maxima.index + pd.DateOffset(hours=23)
maxima = maxima.reindex(df.index, method='bfill')
df.join(df.divide(maxima), rsuffix='_div')
```

Comment: df.join(df.divide(df.max()), rsuffix='_div') provide the results based on the maximum value in all values the column  but I want the maximum value per year to calculate cell value/max. value per year. as the example mention above.

Comment: @swhh Apologies - I have updated my answer. Does this work?

Comment: sorry for being late to - the last code worked well but if there is a way to remove the word zone of the columns name to compress their names

Comment: @swhh You can rename the columns with `pd.MultiIndex.set_levels`. See, e.g., this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221079/rename-multiindex-columns-in-pandas