# How to remove row and rename multiindex table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have multi index data frame like below and I would like remove the row above 'A' (like shift the dataframe up)

```
metric data data
        F    K
        C    B
 A      2    3
 B      4    5
 C      6    7
 D      8    9
```

desired output

```
ALIAS  data data
metric  F    K
 A      2    3
 B      4    5
 C      6    7
 D      8    9
```

I looked multiple post but could not find anything closer to create desired outcome. How can I achive the desired output ?

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try [`DataFrame.droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) to remove level 2 from the columns, and [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) to update column axis names:

```
df = df.droplevel(level=2, axis=1).rename_axis(['ALIAS', 'metric'], axis=1)
```

Or with the index equivalent methods [`Index.droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.droplevel.html) and [`Index.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.rename.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(2).rename(['ALIAS', 'metric'])
```

`df`:

```
ALIAS  data   
metric    F  K
A         2  3
B         4  5
C         6  7
D         8  9
```

---

Setup:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.arange(2, 10).reshape(-1, 2),
    index=list('ABCD'),
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
        ['data', 'data'],
        ['F', 'K'],
        ['C', 'B']
    ], names=['metric', None, None])
)
```

`df`:

```
metric data   
          F  K
          C  B
A         2  3
B         4  5
C         6  7
D         8  9
```

Comment: thank youu! one question, how would you know rename_axis modifys the 1st column ?

Comment: You're welcome. It doesn't. Those are axis names for each column level. With a pivot_table typically the axis name is the old column header. It describes the contents of the new column headers. But those values are not data in the dataframe simply additional header annotations.

Comment: hımm how would you do if want to modify ‘data’ and ‘f’ column? ssorry asking this to learn more. your answer already elegant!

Comment: What do you mean "modify ‘data’ and ‘f’ column"? Modify how?

Comment: Sorry modify those names for example.

Comment: You'd need to `rename` them. Lots of good examples here -> [Rename MultiIndex columns in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41221079/15497888)