# Rename Names of MultiIndex Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm in trouble with a dataframe created from a `groupby` function.

```
df = base.groupby(['year', 'categ']).agg({'id_prod':'count', 'price':'sum'}).unstack(level=1)
```

it returns this result :
[image: df]

but I would like to rename `id_prod` and `price` to `no_sales` and `revenue` but I don't know how to do that because of the MultiIndex

with the `print(df.columns)`
the result is :

```
MultiIndex([('id_prod', 0),
            ('id_prod', 1),
            ('id_prod', 2),
            (  'price', 0),
            (  'price', 1),
            (  'price', 2)],
           names=[None, 'categ'])
```

So is this `names=[]` I would like to change
Thanks for your help !

Comment: `df = df.rename(columns={'id_prod': 'no_sales', 'price': 'revenue'})` should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but df.rename() isn't working because of the mutiindex, it's not basics columns

Comment: Please see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67458211/10256587). It should work regardless of the multiindex.

Comment: Thanks ! I found the solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df = df.rename(columns={'id_prod': 'no_sales', 'price': 'revenue'}, level=0)
```

The `level=0` indicates where in the multi-index the keys to be renamed can be found.

Answer (score 4):

Short and simple , it would just rename your columns with respect to Multi-index

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
```