# Rename multiindex level based on other level

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe with a multiindex column, more or less like so

```
import pandas as pd

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((("Length", "Weight"), ("Max", "Min"), ("asd",)), names=("Measure", "Info", "Unit"))
df = pd.DataFrame(0., columns=columns, index=range(2))
```

```
>>> df
Measure Length  Weight
Info    Max Min Max Min
Unit    asd asd asd asd
0       0   0   0   0
1       0   0   0   0
```

I would like to change the units based on the measurements. The connection between measure and unit is expressed as a dictionary:

```
measure_to_unit = {"Length": "m", "Weight": "kg"}
```

I have tried using `.replace` but it simply doesn't seem to be the right tool for the job.

The expected result is

```
Measure Length  Weight
Info    Max Min Max Min
Unit    m   m   kg  kg
0       0   0   0   0
1       0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Try `df.columns = measure_to_unit.items()`

Comment: That will work in the example, not on my real data though. I have changed my example to clarify

Comment: Maybe have a look at this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221079/rename-multiindex-columns-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

```
measure_to_unit = {"Length": "m", "Weight": "kg"}

l1, l2, l3 = zip(*df.columns)
newcol = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([l1, l2, [measure_to_unit[i] for i in l1]])
df.set_axis(newcol, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     Length      Weight     
     Max  Min    Max  Min
       m    m     kg   kg
0    0.0  0.0    0.0  0.0
1    0.0  0.0    0.0  0.0
```

---

If the order of your dataframe columns match the order of your index, then you can do this:

```
df.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([measure_to_unit.keys(), measure_to_unit.values()]), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Length Weight
       m     kg
0    0.0    0.0
1    0.0    0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this will work with my initial example but it's not the solution I'm looking for. I have changed the example input to clarify

Comment: @edd313  No, don't think there is a native function to do this, but we can use list comprehension along with your dictionary to define the third level using from_arrays in pd.MultiIndex.